# Facebook API getting Privacy settings for `statuses` and `photos`

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using facebook's API `/{uid}/statuses`, `/{uid}/links` and `/{uid}/photos`. I'm trying to filter only to public posts, so I'm trying to get the `privacy` settings and filter according to that (better way?). This seems to work only in the `links` endpoint, adding `fields=privacy` to the others doesn't work.

How can I get the privacy settings of statuses and photos?

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional design. /photo and /statuses do not return Post nodes (which expose a privacy field), but rather Status and Photo; the documentation suggests there is no privacy field on a Status object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/status). Photo objects may specify the field on creation, but it is not exposed on read (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo).

Comment: the /links also doesn't return Post nodes, and it's also not documented to include the privacy, but somehow it exists. Any alternative way to get the privacy setting for statuses and photos?